# How to take the backup of tables from one schema to another schema

Tags: oracle10g

Scenario: I want to take backup of one schema tables to another schema in the Same database.

Existing design: Dropping the indexes on backup tables and truncating the data, finally loading the data into backup tables( Usign insert query).

Requirement: Existing design is taking more time to process. Please suggest me is there any other way to achieve this......

Thanks.

Comment: do you have to use SQL code to achieve this? Can you take backup and restore tables into another schema?

Comment: Yes i wanna PLSQL code to achieve this.

Comment: You can go through method mentioned [here](http://www.pythian.com/blog/oracle-how-to-move-a-table-to-another-schema/) using table partitions, you create partition, table structure using existing table in new schema and then exchange partition.

Comment: I forgot to add that point in my existing design table partitions are there. So pls suggest how to improve the performance

Answer (score 2):

If you have a non-trivial amount of data, and you're already doing the "obvious" things to make it run fast (direct path inserts, parallel mainly, `nologging` if you can afford that), there's probably not much more you can do sticking with SQL.

One thing you could try though is using data pump schema export/import with the `remap_schema` option. The process would be:

- Export the source schema with `expdp` (in [SCHEMAS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#i1007024) mode)
- Drop the target schema and recreate it (empty)
- Import the dump with `impdp` and the `remap_schema=source:target` option (see [`REMAP_SCHEMA`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#sthref339)).

You can skip the second step and use `table_exists_action=replace` during the import instead - might be faster, and certainly is better if the target schema has other objects (see [`TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#sthref364).)

If you want to stay "in the database" to automate this, there is an API for data pump: [`DBMS_DATAPUMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_datpmp.htm).